# How to configure ext-ldap php

Tags: php, linux, ldap, termux

I have installed openldap.
I have tried in 2 ways.

**Way 1**- From the source ext

```
phpize
./configure --with-ldap=include --prefix=$prefix --build=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-php-config=$prefix/bin/php-config
```

**Resulting in gives error:**

> checking for ldap_refresh_s... no
> checking for ldap_bind_s... no
> configure: error: LDAP build check failed. Please check config.log

**Way 2-** Downloaded files from : [pkgs aarch64](https://pkgs.org/download/php-ldap)
Manually cp corresponding files and tried to enable extension ldap from php.ini
then `php -i | grep ldap` gives error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ldap' (tried: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/php/ldap (dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/php/ldap" not found), /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/php/ldap.so (dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found)) in Unknown on line 0

---

tried to `ln libc.so.6 from lib64/libc.so`
no luck yet